# CSS clip-path with polygon weird behaviour

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I was trying to make this shape for [CSS battle](https://cssbattle.dev/play/60).

[image: shape I need]

Here's my styles.

```css
body {
    background: #191919;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #4F77FF;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50px 50px,
                               100px 0, 150px 50px,
                               200px 0, 200px 50px,
                               150px 100px, 100px 50px,
                               50px 100px, 0 50px,
                               0 100px, 50px 150px,
                               100px 100px, 150px 150px,
                               200px 150px, 200px 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Isn't clip-path supposed to cut the right bottom corner too? I don't get it, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your last coordinate is not correct. Instead of `200px 150px`, you need `200px 100px`. Here is your updated snippets:

```css
body {
    background: #191919;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #4F77FF;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50px 50px,
                               100px 0, 150px 50px,
                               200px 0, 200px 50px,
                               150px 100px, 100px 50px,
                               50px 100px, 0 50px,
                               0 100px, 50px 150px,
                               100px 100px, 150px 150px,
                               200px 100px, 200px 0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```